# How can I keep the My Pictures folder synchronised with SmugMug?

Tags: photo-sharing, synchronization, photos

How can I keep the `My Pictures` folder synchronized with my [SmugMug](http://www.smugmug.com) account?

Ideally, I would like new folders added to `My Pictures` to be automatically added and edits automatically uploaded.  However, I also want the possibility of deleting a folder from `My Pictures` without deleting the corresponding album from SmugMug.

However, I recognize this may be a little demanding.  If so, what synchronization tools *are* available, and what are their capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really syncing, but you can use Picasa to upload a folder of files to [SmugMug](http://www.smugmug.com/) using the [Picasa plugin for SmugMug](http://www.smugmug.com/help/picasa-smugmug-uploader)... Unfortunately, [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) will only synchronize with [PicasaWeb](http://picasaweb.google.com/) as far as I know.

There was [some](http://www.dgrin.com/showthread.php?t=109934) [talk](http://www.photographybay.com/2008/06/03/smugmug-to-enable-powerful-syncing/) about SmugMug integration with MS Sync Framework / SyncToy a couple of years ago, but that all seems to have gone quiet.